# One checkbox is checked at a time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, checkbox

I making a WPF app. I have 3 checkboxes and I want to allow only one checkbox is checked at a time. If another one is checked, the previously checked one is unchecked. How could I do that?

Comment: checkbox group may be?

Comment: use [radiobutton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RadioButton` gives this functionality already. If you don't like how it looks, style it to look like a check box.

Given that people already expect multi-select when using check boxes and single select for radio buttons though, I wouldn't recommend changing the appearance too drastically.

Radio buttons can also be "grouped" so that you can select one out of a group of three, one out of another group of 4 (or 2 or whatever) and so on. See the `GroupName` property ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname(v=vs.110).aspx)).

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I haven't jumped into it too far so I'll go with RadioButton.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use radio buttons list?
If you still want the checkboxes, you can look one approach here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520676/CheckBoxList-acts-like-RadioButtonList

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="UserCheckbox" class="custom-control-input chkStatus" id="@item.Id" value="@item.Id" onchange="EditUser(this)">

    function EditUser(Item) {
        if (Item.checked) {
            $('input.chkStatus').not(Item).prop('checked', false); 
        }   
    }
```